# How to show the result page of rake doc:app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I used 
    rake doc:app
 and everything is fine , but how to see the result in the browser?
Routes for doc/app are not created and i can't access to it by localhost:3000/doc/app/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated documents are placed in the `doc/app/` directory. Just open the files with your browser.

For example, if you are using Mac or any other operating system with a `open` command:

```sh
cd /path/to/your/project
open doc/app/index.html
```